# Complex analogue of the golden ratio

Tags: number-theory, gaussian-integers, eisenstein-integers

Golden ratio $\phi$ and related numbers give the largest errors when approximated by rational numbers.
I imagine that if we consider approximations of complex numbers by gaussian rationals or eisenstein rationals then other numbers may appear that are even more difficult to approximate.

**My question is**: is there a complex number $\xi$ such that there is at most finite number of gaussian rationals  $a_n\over b_n$ such that
$$ \left |\xi-\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right | < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}\, |b_n|^2}$$
**Another question**: If yes, is there a real number $r$ such that for every complex $\xi$ there are infinite gaussian rationals $a_n\over b_n$ for which the following inequality holds?
$$ \left |\xi-\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right | < \frac{1}{r\, |b_n|^2}.$$
Is there the largest such $r$? What numbers require the this largest $r$?

I also want to ask both of the questions above but with eisenstein rationals instead of gaussian rationals.